# Changing the the range for MODIS NDVI

Tags: modis, ndvi

I need to get MODIS NDVI (MOD13A3), but output from EarthExplorer or Daac2Disk HDF format is a numerical range is -2000 to 9996.

But I need for futher work basic range -1 to 1.

Is there any conversion method?

Answer (score 2):

[The product description page](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/dataset_discovery/modis/modis_products_table/mod13a3) says the following:

Science Data Sets

- (HDF Layers) (11): 1km monthly NDVI
- UNITS: NDVI
- BIT: 16-bit
- TYPE: signed integer
- FILL: -3000
- VALID RANGE: -2000, 10000
- MULTIPLY BY SCALE FACTOR: 0.0001

My first guess would be to multiply your data with 0.0001 to get to the correct NDVI values. You could use an additional conditional statement to set -3000 values to nan/nodata

UPDATE: I guess in your case the fill value might not be set

UPDATE2: [Here](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/258757960_Correlation_between_the_habitats_productivity_and_species_richness_(amphibians_and_reptiles)_in_Portugal_through_remote_sensed_data) is the description (p. 5)

> "MOD13A3 product
>   As presented in Table 2, the NDVI value given in
>   MOD13A3 products is a integer (16 bits) and range between -2000 and 10
>   000. In order to convert these values in NDVI “true” values was necessary to apply a scale factor. Therefore, all the original data
>   were multiplied by 0.0001 and the final values were in the range
>   between -0.2 and 1.0. "

Answer (score 0):

The scale factor of 0.0001 just brings the range to [-0.2 1.0]. To rescale the MODIS NDVI data to the [-1 1] range that is typical for NDVI, you can use this formula, after removing the -3000 fill values of course.

To rescale a vector A from [a b] to [c d]:

c + [(A-a) / (b-a)] * (d-c)

Where:

- A = MODIS NDVI array
- a = -2000 (or -0.2 if you have applied the 0.0001 scale factor)
- b = 10000 (1.0 if you applied the scale factor)
- c = -1
- d = 1